# How can I remove these gaps in my table?

Tags: tables

```
% Please add the following required packages to your document preamble:
% \usepackage{booktabs}
% \usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\caption{}
\label{tab:my-table}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{@{}|l|c|@{}}
\toprule
Abschnitt                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           & Verfasser    \\ \midrule
Abstract                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            & Luise Fabich \\ \midrule
1. Einleitung                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       & Luise Fabich \\ \midrule
2. Literatur\"ubersicht                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               & Luise Fabich \\ \midrule
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}3. Problembeschreibung und mathematische Modellierung\\   3.1. Problembeschreibung\\   3.2. Mathematische Modellierung\end{tabular}                                                                                                                                      & Renxian Lu   \\ \midrule
\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}4. Experiment \\   4.1. Test Instanzen\\   4.2. Berechnungsergebnisse\\     4.2.1. Die Einfluss der Kapazit\"at des Fahrzeuges\\     4.2.2. Die Einfluss der Bedienungszeit bei dem Kunden\\     4.2.3. Die Einfluss der Gr\"o\ss{}e des Zeitfensters bei dem Kunden\end{tabular} & Renxian Lu   \\ \midrule
4.3 Diskussion                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      & Renxian Lu   \\ \midrule
5. Schlussbemerkungen                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               & Luise Fabich \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
}
\end{table}
```

How can I remove these gaps in my table?
[image]

Comment: see the booktabs package documentation. by design vertical rules are unusable if you use booktabs.

Comment: *Testinstanzen btw

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In addition to learning to omit all vertical rules while employing the line-drawing macros of the booktabs package, you should also learn to avoid the `\resizebox` sledgehammer. For the case at hand, an excellent alternative is readily available: the [tabularx](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) package and its eponymous environment. Set its overall width to `\textwidth`, employ the `X` column type for the first column, get rid of the internal `tabular` environments, and replace the column-internal instances of `\\` with `\newline`.

About employing the booktabs package: I suggest you replace all but one instance of `\midrule` with `\addlinespace`, to achieve a more open and inviting "look".

Finally, since it's the year 2023, not 1983, just go ahead and use `ä`, `ö`, `ü`, and `ß` directly in the body of your LaTeX file.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{\strut}
\label{tab:my-table}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} >{\RaggedRight}X l @{}}
\toprule
Abschnitt & Verfasser \\ 
\midrule
Abstract & Luise Fabich \\ 
\addlinespace
1. Einleitung & Luise Fabich \\ 
\addlinespace
2. Literaturübersicht & Luise Fabich \\ 
\addlinespace
3. Problembeschreibung und mathematische Modellierung \newline   
3.1. Problembeschreibung \newline   
3.2. Mathematische Modellierung
  & Renxian Lu \\ 
\addlinespace
4. Experiment \newline   
4.1. Test Instanzen \newline   
4.2. Berechnungsergebnisse \newline     
4.2.1. Die Einfluss der Kapazität des Fahrzeuges \newline     
4.2.2. Die Einfluss der Bedienungszeit bei dem Kunden \newline     
4.2.3. Die Einfluss der Größe des Zeitfensters bei dem Kunden
  & Renxian Lu \\ 
\addlinespace
4.3 Diskussion & Renxian Lu \\ 
\addlinespace
5. Schlussbemerkungen & Luise Fabich \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{title}
\label{tab:my-table}
\begin{tblr}{colspec={X[l,m]Q[l,m]},vlines,hlines}
Abschnitt & Verfasser \\
Abstract & Luise Fabich \\
1. Einleitung & Luise Fabich \\
2. Literatur\"ubersicht & Luise Fabich \\
{3. Problembeschreibung und mathematische Modellierung\\3.1. Problembeschreibung\\3.2. Mathematische Modellierung} & Renxian Lu \\
{4. Experiment\\4.1. Test Instanzen\\4.2. Berechnungsergebnisse\\4.2.1. Die Einfluss der Kapazit\"at des Fahrzeuges\\4.2.2. Die Einfluss der Bedienungszeit bei dem Kunden\\4.2.3. Die Einfluss der Gr\"o\ss{}e des Zeitfensters bei dem Kunden} & Renxian Lu \\
4.3 Diskussion & Renxian Lu \\
5. Schlussbemerkungen & Luise Fabich \\
\end{tblr}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1, it is better than mine ...

Comment: @Zarko I prefer to use `hline{1,Z}={wd=.08em},hline{2}={wd=.05em}` rather than `booktabs`.

Comment: That is matter of taste. To me is easy to use booktabs. However, At writing of my answer  I didn't remember on `{...\\...|\\...}` construct :-(.

Answer (score 3):

Without `tabularx`:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{table}[ht]
        \caption{\strut}
        \label{tab:my-table}
        \begin{tabular}{lll}
            \toprule
            &Abschnitt & Verfasser \\ 
            \midrule
            &Abstract & Luise Fabich \\ 
            \addlinespace
            1. &Einleitung & Luise Fabich \\ 
            \addlinespace
            2. &Literaturübersicht & Luise Fabich \\ 
            \addlinespace
            3. &Problembeschreibung und mathematische Modellierung &\\  
            3.1. &Problembeschreibung &\\    
            3.2. &Mathematische Modellierung & Renxian Lu \\ 
            \addlinespace
            4. &Experiment &\\   
            4.1. &Test Instanzen &\\   
            4.2. &Berechnungsergebnisse &\\     
            4.2.1. &Die Einfluss der Kapazität des Fahrzeuges &\\     
            4.2.2. &Die Einfluss der Bedienungszeit bei dem Kunden &\\     
            4.2.3. &Die Einfluss der Größe des Zeitfensters bei dem Kunden
            & Renxian Lu \\ 
            \addlinespace
            4.3 &Diskussion & Renxian Lu \\ 
            \addlinespace
            5. &Schlussbemerkungen & Luise Fabich \\ 
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. You may want to point out somewhere that the reason this approach, which doesn't allow automatic line-breaking in cells, works is that none of the cell contents of the OP's sample code are long enough to require line-breaking in order to make the table fit inside the text block.

Answer (score 2):

In the case that you persist to have vertical lines, you may try to employ `tabularray` instead of `tabular` package enclosed in `\resizebox` box:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}

\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \small
\caption{}
\label{tab:my-table}
\begin{tblr}{colspec = { | X[l] | Q[l] | }}
    \toprule
Abschnitt                   & Verfasser     \\ \midrule
Abstract                    & Luise Fabich  \\ \midrule
1. Einleitung               & Luise Fabich  \\ \midrule
2. Literatur\"ubersicht     & Luise Fabich  \\ \midrule
    \makecell[l]{
3. Problembeschreibung und mathematische Modellierung\\   
3.1. Problembeschreibung\\   
3.2. Mathematische Modellierung
                }           & Renxian Lu    \\ \midrule
    \makecell[l]{
4. Experiment \\  
4.1. Test Instanzen\\   
4.2. Berechnungsergebnisse\\     
4.2.1. Die Einfluss der Kapazit\"at des Fahrzeuges\\     
4.2.2. Die Einfluss der Bedienungszeit bei dem Kunden\\     
4.2.3. Die Einfluss der Gr\"o\ss{}e des Zeitfensters bei dem Kunden
                }           & Renxian Lu    \\ \midrule
4.3 Diskussion              & Renxian Lu    \\ \midrule
5. Schlussbemerkungen       & Luise Fabich  \\ \bottomrule
\end{tblr}%
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

or

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \centering
    \small
\caption{}
\label{tab:my-table}
\begin{tblr}{colspec = { | X[l] | Q[l] | }}
    \toprule
Abschnitt                   & Verfasser     \\ \midrule
Abstract                    & Luise Fabich  \\ \midrule
1. Einleitung               & Luise Fabich  \\ \midrule
2. Literatur\"ubersicht     & Luise Fabich  \\ \midrule

3. Problembeschreibung und mathematische Modellierung\par   
3.1. Problembeschreibung\par   
3.2. Mathematische Modellierung
                            & Renxian Lu    \\ \midrule

4. Experiment \par  
4.1. Test Instanzen\par   
4.2. Berechnungsergebnisse\par     
4.2.1. Die Einfluss der Kapazit\"at des Fahrzeuges\par    
4.2.2. Die Einfluss der Bedienungszeit bei dem Kunden\par     
4.2.3. Die Einfluss der Gr\"o\ss{}e des Zeitfensters bei dem Kunden
                            & Renxian Lu    \\ \midrule
4.3 Diskussion              & Renxian Lu    \\ \midrule
5. Schlussbemerkungen       & Luise Fabich  \\ \bottomrule
\end{tblr}%
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

In both cases compilation result is the same:

[image]